# Lucene.Net (2.9.2.2) and Nhibernate.Search

Tags: c#, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I would like to use Lucene.Net ver. 2.9.2.2 with nHibernate Search.
I would like to use one of the latest nhibernate versions, possibly.
I've seen there's a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NHibernate.Search) in the gallery but it doesn't work for me.
When I try to compile I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f5940d1699e37ff1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Is there any other place where I can download nHibernate.Search compatible with the latests versione of Lucene.et?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download NHibernate.Search source code via svn here :

https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Search

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it. Now you can use the [nuget package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NHibernate.Search)